# Control the order of json data columns returned in the Json() method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a table `Articles` with following colums:

```
ID, Title, Excerpts, Content
```

Corresponding MVC model class:

```
public class Articles
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Excerpts { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

I have store procedure which returns the data from `Articles` table in a particular order of columns which are configured by the user in another table. For example if the columns are in the order of `Title, ID, Content, Excerpts` then the stored procedure will return result set like:

```
Title   ID  Content Excerpts
Data    1   Data    Data
Data    2   Data    Data
....
```

I am storing the result set of the above stored procedure in a List<> of `Articles` object and converting it to `json` using the `return Json()` and binding it in the screen using Knockout.

The problem I am facing is that the data after getting converted to `json` format is retaining the order of columns as it declared in the `Articles MVC model class` and not how it is returned from the stored procedure. If I declare the properties of the `Articles` class in the following order, then the converted `json` is taking the column order based on order of properties declared in the class:

```
public class MTB_Articles
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Excerpts { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

In the above case, the data is binding in the screen in the `Title, Content, Excerpts, ID` order. All I want is to format the `json` data in the same way it is returned from the stored procedure. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Keep in mind that Json by definition is an unordered set of name/value pairs. Maybe you can modify your Knockout binding logic and use things like this instead? `var parsedJson = JSON.parse(yourJson); viewModel.myPropoerty(parsed.jsonProp);`

Comment: @MaxS-Betclic I have solved the problem by changing binding logic in knockout as you said but what I asked in my question, is that possible in anyway?

Comment: Glad to read that it helped. Well, as I said, Json has been built as an unordered set of name/value pairs. If you try to change that behavior, then it's not Json anymore. What you could do is to create your own Json-like string rather than using `return Json()` but I won't encourage you to do that!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the WCF Data Contract. Thanks for the tip

```
[DataMember(Order = 0)]

public string OrderID { get; set; }

[DataMember(Order = 1)] 

public string OrderDate { get; set; }
```